# Apt-Get Install Unmet Dependencies

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, system-installation, dependencies

My debian computer will not install the new kernel. It says I have unmet dependencies, and those dependencies say they have unmet dependencies. Many of these dependencies are already installed however. Running apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, and apt-get install -f do not fix the problem. My sources list is as follows:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

# Debian Squeeze Backports
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

I've tried installing from the sqeeze-backports and still no luck. Do you guys know what might be going on?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: grab the dependency errors, drop them in a paste bin for us all to see?

Comment: Maybe purge them and reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install from `squeeze-backports`, you should tell it to `apt-get` with the `-t` parameter, and specify the version of the package you want, i.e.:

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports <package-name>=<version>
```

In order to know which version is provided by a given repository, you can use the `apt-cache show` command, and look for the info of the package in that repository.

In your case, the command should be:

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports linux-image-2.6-amd64=3.2+45~bpo60+1
```

for an linux amd64 kernel.

Of course, you may have to run the usual `apt-get update` first, and if a new kernel package has been uploaded, you might have to replace `3.2+45~bpo60+1` with the new package version.

If you want to install the 3.2 kernel, then the command is:

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64=3.2.23-1~bpo60+2
```

but you might omit the version number if you don't have any other repository hosting that kernel in your source list (ie, you don't have testing or unstable).

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, I had some weird issues going on with firmware, but got it all fixed. Thanks for the help :)